# Using Parallel.ForEach for sending emails

Tags: c#, smtpclient, parallel.foreach

After some testing of the I am not sure if I am dealing with the problem correctly, because running the program with `Parallel.ForEach` takes more time than `foreach`. I split it into steps:

1. Read a `*.eml` file:

   `var newMailMessage = Sasa.Net.Mail.Message.Parse(File.ReadAllText(config.TemplateFilePath));`
2. Load a recipients list:

   `var recipients = RecipientHelper.LoadFromFile(config.MailListFilePath);`
3. Split this list into chunks:

   `var recipientChunks = recipients.Chunk(config.MessagesPerBlock.Value);`

and then I am doing:

```
foreach (var chunk in recipientChunks)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(chunk.AsParallel(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = recipientChunks.Count() },
                        (recipient, state, index) =>
                    {
                        using (var client = new SmtpClient(config.SmtpHost, config.SmtpPort.Value))
                        {
                            lock (syncRoot)
                            {
var mailMessage = new Postman(recipient, newMailMessage, config).PrepareMail();
client.Send(mailMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have tested this code with 15,000 email and it tooks 2,5min to send all but while I was doing it using `foreach` it tooks 2 min. How to improve this code?

I would like to have a `SMTP` connection for each chunk, and these chunks should be send in parallel.

**EDITED**

Ok If I remove the `lock` my mails are not correctly prepared, for example I have some problems with streams, I am already using `Stream.Synchronized(linkedResource.ContentStream)`, emails have different sizes etc. So how to deal with this?

The source code of `Chunk`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int size)
    {
        T[] array = items as T[] ?? items.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += size)
        {
            T[] chunk = new T[Math.Min(size, array.Length - i)];
            Array.Copy(array, i, chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
            yield return chunk;
        }
    }
```

Is `Parallel.ForEach` good for `I/O` operation? should be used in this scenario?

All of the emails from each chunk should be send via different `SMTP` connection.

Comment: if you have code (which isnt here) that does our foreach and parallel for each you would be best directed to codereview

Comment: `lock(syncRoot)` ? You're parallellising a sequential task here.

Comment: First, you could move the line: var mailMessage = new Postman(recipient, newMailMessage, config).PrepareMail(); out of the lock statement, since it does not depend on client... if you can't do it, try to find a way to parallelize it...

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(chunk.AsParallel()` You don't need both of those. Remove the `AsParallel()`.

Comment: if I do this my mails wont be properly constructed, for example `LinkedResource` which are streams.

Comment: Then you could try to move this line out of the lock statement: client.Send(mailMessage);  Otherwise you don't need a parallel loop. Just declare 'Postman mailMessage;' outside the lock statement...

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `newMailMessage` comes from. Could you clearify?

Comment: `newMailMessage` is a `MailMessage` type, loaded from `*.eml` file.

Comment: Where is `LinkedResource` being attached? When you removed `AsParallel` how long did it take?

Comment: Can you show us the source code for `Chunk`?

Comment: `I would like to have a SMTP connection for each chunk, and these chunks should be send in parallel.` Currently your parallelism is **within** a chunk. Is that what you want? Or do you want parallelism **across** chunks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line of code:

```
lock (syncRoot)
```

Since this object doesn't appear to be related to anything in those loops, nor constructed inside those loops, it has to be external, and thus the same object across all the parallel tasks.

As such, the code inside that lock will run sequentially.

Comment: I am creating a MailMessage inside `lock`, I am using there `Stream` so I had to do this, because without it the emails did not have properly attached `LinkedResource` etc.

Comment: The lock is on shared object - as it should be - which leads to your parallelForEach being executed sequentially. Plus the overhead of the locking and the collisions that occurs. No wonder the parallel is slower than the normal foreach.

Comment: So you're saying you want to run code in parallel that cannot be run in parallel? Well the obvious answer to that is that you can't.

Comment: When you removed the `lock` @TomaszKowalczyk what didn't work? Also, what is the type of `client`?

Comment: `client` is `SmtpClient`. How to be sure that my code cant be run on Parallel, if I am dealing with Streams in `Postman` it means that it cant be run in parallel?